# How to change editor font (line numbers) in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, fonts

My OS system default language is set to Japanese. When I start NetBeans IDE 7.x.x editor window fonts are automatically set to OS system default (it is some Japanese font) - but I want all to be **Courier New** font. So I successfully changed it in editor window (where the code is written) and in Output window. But code line numbers is still in Japanese font (for me digits look to narrow). Is it possible to change them also to **Courier New** font?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make an update to Netbeans >=7.2.0. Your bug could be fixed with version 7.2.0. See the ticket in the [Netbeans Bugtracker](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203863).

Comment: I've tried also NetBeans IDE 7.4 - no luck. So I submitted my request to NetBeans community page [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222015)

Answer (score 0):

**Caution**: This workaround might help by configuring how JRE handles fonts. As a rule of thumb, always make a copy (backup) of what you're messing w/ beforehand; and try the followings at your own risk!

1. Go to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/` and you shall see a file `fontconfig.properties.src`, duplicate it and rename the duplicated file to `fontconfig.properties`.
   Open `fontconfig.properties` and look for these lines:

> monospaced.plain.japanese=***{???}***
>
> monospaced.bold.japanese=***{???}***
>
> monospaced.italic.japanese=***{???}***
>
> monospaced.bolditalic.japanese=***{???}***

and change them to:

> monospaced.plain.japanese=***Courier New***
>
> monospaced.bold.japanese=***Courier New Bold***
>
> monospaced.italic.japanese=***Courier New Italic***
>
> monospaced.bolditalic.japanese=***Courier New Bold Italic***

respectively.

The logic behind this is to configure a font (**`Courier New`** in the case) to be used when **`monospaced`** is specificed (used); and since the line numbers (as well as gutter area) of the NetBeans IDE uses **`monospaced`** as its UI font, I just thought (and hope) this might help you!
Beware though, this would also affect anything else that use this JRE!

Comment: I've tried to change that in my Java JDK (JRE inside), also JRE, restarted my PC, but no change to NetBeans.. Maybe it looks somewhere for other settings? I can live with that :) but would be nice to have such ability. Thanks 高科技黑手